# Exception Unhandeled in Iterators use in C++ Program

Tags: c++, exception, vector, iterator

The error message was given in a program using vector iterator to delete common elements inside the vector. The execution stop just before showing the contained elements of the vector. What is wrong with this. The compiler used is MSVC and I am using visual studio. 
This function is called in main() without any problem.

```
#include"sample.h"
#include<iostream>
#include<vector>
#include<algorithm>
using namespace std;
void ex_vector::prac_vector()
{

    vector<int> vec;
    int input = 0,i=0;
    vector<int>::iterator iter, iter_end;

    //INSERT Values inside a vector
    while (i!=10)
    {
        cin >> input;
        vec.push_back(input);
        ++i;
    }

    //PRINT the values inside the vector
    std::cout << "\nThe container has elements \n";
    iter = vec.begin();
    iter_end = vec.end();
    while (iter!=iter_end)
    {
        cout <<*iter++ << " ";
    }

    //DELETES the common values
    iter = vec.begin();
    iter_end = vec.end();
    std::cout << "\nDeleting common value in the vector\n";
    vector<int>::iterator elem = vec.begin();
    while (iter != vec.end())
    {
        while (elem  != vec.end()) //<--Issue raised
        {
            elem = find(iter + 1, vec.end(), *iter);
            if (elem != vec.end())
            {
                elem=vec.erase(elem);
            }
        }
       ++iter;
    }

    //PRINT the OUTPUT
    iter = vec.begin();
    while (iter != iter_end)
    {
        std::cout << *iter++ << " ";
    }
    cout << "\n ";
}
```

[Error dialog box as thrown](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9wl3F.jpg)

[Error pointed to library here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1pfZf.jpg)

Comment: The debugger is your friend. Step line by line through your code.

Comment: I think you got a typo in your post right below the error comment, please fix that first

Comment: What is the "ERROR MESSAGE"? If you get a build error, please copy-paste it full and complete into the question body.

Comment: Any suggestion where I can learn any of my program to debug?

Comment: Yes, sure, plenty. Check here: https://www.google.com/search?q=debugging+c%2B%2B+visual+studio

Comment: Also: it is a bad practice to post images here (unless some specific situations). So in the future, you'd better copy/paste the error text instead of a screenshot.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I hope I get to know a lot from you. Can you please also tell me ```Replace the usage of "std::cout" by a logger.``` Sonarlint keeps on warning me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edit** *typo in the question was now fixed*

Some hints, that might help you:

```
vector<int> vec(10, 0);
```

Effectively creates an int-vector already containing 10 elements with the value 0 - was that your intention? I think you really wanted to limit the max number of elements to 10 - in this case you could maybe just use an array.

```
vector<int>::iterator iter = vec.begin(), iter_end = vec.end();

//INSERT Values inside a vector
while (i!=10)
{
    cin >> input;
    vec.push_back(input);
    ++i;
}
```

This definitely can cause an incompatible vector error. Because when you change your vector **afterwards** by calling `push_back` the previously defined iterators become incompatible.

Focusing the deleting part of the code, there might be an error for assigning `elem` what leads to an invalid iterator value (especially when not erasing) but we do not know your function `find` and what it returns.
But if the purpose really is to find duplicates in your vector you might just do something like this:

```
std::vector<int>::iterator i = vec.begin();
std::vector<int>::iterator j;

while (i != vec.end())
{
   j = i + 1;
   while ( j != vec.end())
   {
      if (*i == *j)
         vec.erase(j);

      j++;
   }

   i++;
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Odysseus. Now the exception thrown is this. As you told _Typos_ were eleminated. and the vector is now  **NOT INITIALIZED** . But now this is shown.```Exception thrown: read access violation.
**_Mycont** was nullptr. occurred```

Comment: Now you still have an vector containing 10 uninitialized elements and then 10 more elements are added with user input values => Now you have a vector of 20 elements (just in case that is really your purpose to have not only the entered values within your vector).

But read again my 2nd hint - you still initialize your iterators `iter=vec.begin() iter_end=vec.end()` before filling with another 10 elements. You should do that just before iterating when adjusting of the vector is completed

Comment: Thanks again @Odysseus. As you told I tried fixing it. Learnt debugging VS , checked memory. But keeping getting the same error. ```Iterators Incompatible```.

Comment: Do you still get the error when printing the values? I would recommend to divide your code - just the part for entering values and printing them afterwards - comment out the rest of it. This part works fine for me, but I cannot reproduce the 2nd part unless it is unclear what your `find` function does

Comment: Regarding that. The find function checks if the value dereferenced by ```*iterr``` exist forward of ```iter``` **IF** **It** **Does** then ```erase``` function is called to erase the value **until** ```elem``` is not equal to ``vec.end()```. And this is done for every element in the ```vector```.

Comment: I tried recreating the issue.  ```std::vector<int> vec1={ 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0 };
 std::vector<int>::iterator itr;
 itr = vec1.();
 while (itr != vec1.end())
  vec1.erase(itr);```  This gives the exact same exception of  ```Incompatible Iterators``` as given by inner loop of _deleting elements_. While this down here works perfectly fine. ```std::vector<int> vec1={ 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0 };
 std::vector<int>::iterator itr;
 itr = vec1.();
 while (itr != vec1.end())
  itr=vec1.erase(itr);```

Comment: In the former case the iterator is not changed after you delete the element at its position - so for example you delete the first element of the vector and in the next cycle `itr` still points to this element which is not existing anymore. In the latter case you reassign `itr` to the return value of `erase` which is the position after the erased one (check [ref](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/erase) ). So this is almost the same as: `while(itr != vec1.end()) { vec1.erase(itr); itr++; }`

Comment: Exactly. The same implementation of assigning ```iter``` to next elem doesn't help me though for the next iteration of the nested loop.

Comment: So your error when printing values is solved and your are now struggling with the deleting part of your code in your question?

Comment: Yes. It's like that.